# Scrapy AttributeError: 'XmlExportPipeline' object has no attribute 'exporter'

Tags: python, anaconda, scrapy

I have been experimenting with Scrapy and trying to learn more about it using this scraper for football data - https://github.com/hugomathien/football-data-collection

Now everything is working except **exporting the data**.

I keep getting this error.

```
ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method XmlExportPipeline.spider_closed of <footballData.pipelines.XmlExportPipeline object at 0x1031c0ac8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/Users/footballData/footballData/pipelines.py", line 43, in spider_closed
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
AttributeError: 'XmlExportPipeline' object has no attribute 'exporter'
```

I won't copy the full code to save space - can be seen here - https://github.com/hugomathien/football-data-collection/blob/master/footballData/footballData/pipelines.py

I haven't been able to find the exact error so far but could it be due to **twisted** module or **pydispatch?**

Comment: The problem is because the code creates the `exporter` object only when a item is returned. If you run the match scraper right now, no item is scraped and hence the object doesn't get created and the error

Comment: So the issue is actually with the spider and is not scraping anything correct?

Comment: That you will have to check, but error is because there is no data scraped. It could be either no data is there or it has bug for not scraping

Comment: Definitely think no data is being scraped. I tried running `scrapy crawl project -o file.csv` and the file saved but it was empty

Comment: I had the same issue, the problem was the file it had to save to was already open hence it couldn't export.